# Regular Expressions \b anchor (.net)

Tags: .net, regex

I am getting familiar with \b anchor on Regular Expressions (working on .net) and I don't understand why

```
@"\b\w+\s\w+\b"
```

does not match

```
"theme them"
```

IN

```
"them theme them them"
```

I believe the spaces are non-word characters so a boundary exists at both ends of (2), so it should be a match.

Can someone explain me why I am wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It won't match the substring `theme them` because of overlapping of matches.

At first this `\b\w+\s\w+\b` regex would match `them theme` and then it checks for the strings which satisfy the pattern. So then it matches `them them`. It won't match the in-between `theme them` because the substring `theme` is already matched.

You need to use positive lookahead in-order to match a string which was already matched.

```
@"(?=(\b\w+\s\w+\b))"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4gD6/4)